# Multiple deployments, one machine, how to expose them all

Tags: juju, wordpress

In juju, if you were to create multiple wordpress (or any other) deployments on the same machine, how would you set that up such that all of those sites could be simultaneously exposed while being viewable?

Comment: what do you mean "exposed while being viewable"? Do you mean, make all the WP sites viewable at once? What is serving the WP sites?

Comment: Multiple apps answering to different urls on one server. E.g. wordpress1juju.com, wordpress2juju.com, mediawiki1juju.com... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is no easy way to do this. There is some container support in Juju but network addressability issues still exist. In the near future you'll be able to deploy multiple charms to a single machine using either LXC or KVM containers.

You could fork the WordPress charm and add WordPress Multi User support. It's on the roadmap for that charm but progress is slow.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately I don't know a lot about Juju specifically, but I suspect something like this may be possible:

- wordpress1 deployed and listening on local port 8001
- wordpress2 deployed and listening on local port 8002
- wordpress3 deployed and listening on local port 8003

These sites would then be *proxied* to the outside world by something like Apache using name-based virtual hosts. Assuming you have only one routable IP address, you'd then set up Apache to listen on that IP and expose a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html) in such a way that clients requesting wordpress1juju.com are connected to the server running on 8001, etc.

Someone with Juju experience would likely know how to do this sort of thing in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

By viewable, do you mean accessible by something other than your computer? If so, it's probably the firewall. try:

`sudo ufw disable`

Then try to access from another machine.

When done, run:

`sudo ufw enable`

If turning off firewall worked, you may want to [configure your firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) to let in port 80 (http)

Comment: Changing firewall rules won't help. The problem is containers are on a network, which is not visible outside the host (a 10.x.x.x network). We're currently working on native networking support for containers in juju-core, so it will be possible to do that most likely for the 14.04 release.

Comment: Actually, I can confirm it does block incoming 80 connections. If you want to go to http://(your computer IP) on another computer, you must change or disable the firewall (though I haven't tried with Juju, it probably sets this up for you?)

Comment: No, Juju does not touch your local firewall rules. If you block port 80 yourself, of course it won't be accessible from outside your machine. Right now you can probably play around with custom networking settings, bridging, NAT, etc. to expose the 10.x.x.x LXC network addresses through your host's network, but you're on your own. As I said, networking for containers is being worked on  in juju-core at the moment.